# Accessing RDS through bastion host with port forwarding not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, portforwarding

I'm trying to establish a port forwarding to my RDS in a private subnet via a bastion host in a public subnet with the following command:

```
ssh -A  -NL 3007:mydb3.co2qgzotzkku.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 ubuntu@ec2-562243-250-177.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

but cant get a connection to the rds instance.

The security group for the Bastion Host allows only SSH on port 22 from my IP

[image]

and the security group for the RDS allows traffic from the bastion hosts security group and SSH from my iP

[image]

Besides the ACL for the subnets are open to all traffic for TCP.

anybody a tip what is missing to get the tunnel running?

merci A

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the port `3306` and `3307`. Allow that port in the both security group and it will work.

As you said you are accessing the bastion via key-pair, your new command must be:

`ssh -N -L 3007:mydb3.co2qgzotzkku.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 ubuntu@ec2-562243-250-177.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com -i /path/to/key.pem`

I would suggest removing `A` from the command as it Enables forwarding of the authentication agent connection.  This can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file.

Agent forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the agent's UNIX-domain socket) can access the local agent through the forwarded connection.  An attacker cannot obtain key material from the agent, however they can perform operations on the keys that enable them to authenticate using the identities loaded into the agent.

Comment: Actually with all traffic from the Bastion Host allowed into the RDS SG that includes it; but I added the ports 3306 and 3307 in both security groups like:

RDS SG - > inbound - 3306/ 3307 from sg of bastion host
Bastion Host SG - > inbound - 3306/ 3307 from my IP

still not working...

Comment: Run this command from the bastion host: `telnet  mydb3.co2qgzotzkku.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com 3306`. Also, can you tell me from where are you running this command? Is that IP added in the security group for port 22?

Comment: Also, Do you access the Bastion server with a key or not?

Comment: that what I'm getting when I connect via telnet: 
`ubuntu@ip-172-16-47-75:~$ telnet mydb3.co2qgzotzkku.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com 3306                                                              
Trying 172.16.67.158...

Comment: Connected to mydb3.co2qgzotzkku.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com.                                                                                       
Escape character is '^]'.                                                                                                                          
]                                                                                                                                                  
5.5.5-10.2.12-MariaDB-logLgL%q,%q/���5X?r@&>E}iw;mysql_native_passwordConnection closed by foreign host
ubuntu@ip-172-16-47-75:~$

Comment: - I'm running the command in the windows subsystem bash (WSL)
- the IP of my location is added to the Bastion Host source for port 22; as said, I can easily connect via SSH to the bastion Host, no frills, it must be something between the Bastion and the RDS...

and yes I'm acessign the ec2 Bastion with a keypair.pem

Comment: I have updated my answer please try it and let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178744/discussion-between-ashutosh-and-aerioeus).